# Reindex "salesrule_rule" Magento 2 EE

Tags: magento2, reindex, sales, magento-ee

Does anyone know for what is reindex of "salesrule_rule" of Magento 2 EE?

Comment: Seem that there is no reindex of `salesrule_rule`. What are you trying? Can you explain more details?

Comment: Sorry, is for Magento 2 EE. In CE this reindex don't exists.

Comment: Okay! Let's me check again.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh, could you check it?